# SQLAlchemy - override orm.Query.count for a database without subselect

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, crate

I am using sqlalchemy with a database that doesn't support subselects.  What that means is that something like this wouldn't work (where `Calendar` is a model inheriting a declarative base):

```
 Calendar.query.filter(uuid=uuid).count()
```

I am trying to override the `count` method with something like this:

```
def count(self):
    col = func.count(literal_column("'uuid'"))
    return self.from_self(col).scalar()
```

However, the `from_self` bit still does the subselect.  I can't do something like this:

```
session.query(sql.func.count(Calendar.uuid)).scalar()
```

Because I want all the filter information from the `Query`.  Is there a way I can get the filter arguments for the current `Query` without doing the subselect?

Thanks~

Comment: `self.with_entities(col).scalar()`?

Comment: @univerio: your comment is the answer, if you want to post an answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1):

From the SQLAlchemy documentation:

> For fine grained control over specific columns to count, to skip the usage of a subquery or otherwise control of the FROM clause, or to use other aggregate functions, use func expressions in conjunction with query(), i.e.:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

# count User records, without
# using a subquery.
session.query(func.count(User.id))

# return count of user "id" grouped
# by "name"
session.query(func.count(User.id)).\
        group_by(User.name)

from sqlalchemy import distinct

# count distinct "name" values
session.query(func.count(distinct(User.name)))
```

Source: [SQLAlchemy (sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count)

Comment: Concerning filtering you can do: `query = session.query(func.count(Calendar.uuid)).filter(Calendar.uuid=='...')`

Comment: I know how to get the scalar.  I want to override the ORM Query `count`.  The first comment on my question is the answer.